# Git : How to delete all local branches (merged or not), except master and develop

Tags: git, github, gitlab, branch

I want to clean my local branches (merged or not), except `master` and `develop`.

I did some cleanup on the remote repository and I want to have the same locally.

I tried `git fetch --prune` which removed some, but there is still a large amount (over a hundred...).

Comment: What about push develop and master, clean the remote and do a new clone ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this in git out of the box, but this can done with some shell scripting:

```
git branch | grep -v master | grep -v develop | xargs git branch -D
```

Just make sure you are checked out to `master` or `develop` before you start, or this script will also attempt to drop the branch you're currently checked out to (and fail to do so, of course).